# Edittext with inputType="textPassword" has suddenly changed to making passwords Visible instead of being *****

Tags: android, android-edittext, passwords, android-6.0-marshmallow

Weird issue just started happening to me, and I haven't touched that file in months.

The past two days or so I've been working on the new version of Android (6.0) API 23. Today I noticed when trying to login to my app, the password field was completely visible. I've been working on runtime permissions, removing permissions that I don't think I need and adding it code to ask for permissions at runtime. The `Activity` this `EditText` field is in, has not been touched in months. Yet somehow when I type inside it, I can see all the characters. Here is the EditText just to be sure I'm not missed anything obvious:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:textColorHint="@color/light_grey"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"        
    android:textColor="@color/text_gray"/>
```

The app now points to API 23, buildTools 23.0.1 and all support libraries updated to v23.0.1. I tested my app on two phones, one Lollipop 5.1.1, the other on 6.0 M Preview 3. Both have a visible password. In fact there are two Activitesin my app that have a password field, when you register, and when you login, both have `textPassword` as the `inputType` but all characters are visible in both.

I checked the M preview issue tracker and did not find anything so I'm turning here.

One thing that makes be believe this is Android 6.0 related is that I just downloaded our live app from the Google Play Store, which is pointing to API 22 and the `EditText` field works just fine.

Something very peculiar is going on and I can't figure it out. Would really appreciate some input, thanks in advance for any comments you have.

**Edit:** Found out that setting textAllCaps to false in my styles.xml was causing this, no idea why. Something to do with v23.0.1 of AppCompat?

Comment: There's a user setting, under Security, to force all passwords to be visible. Is it possible this is enabled on the phone running M Preview? I was changing this setting to off programmatically in my code when setting up my views containing password fields, but in Android M you now have to request permission.WRITE_SETTINGS to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was just a weird glitch. I removed the following from my styles.xml it worked, then added it back and it carried on working. Not sure what that was about.

```
<item name"textAllCaps>false</item>
```